# Create dynamic link list with foreach

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I got a sitemap in my footer that links to all my pages, some pages have different urls because of a rewrite. For example, pages with id 14 have /projects/ before them, and pages with id 16 have /actueel/.  How can I check on that and build the list?

This doesn't work (it adds projects to the entire list):

```
<?
foreach($menufootercr as $menufooterlist){
  if($menufooterlist['id'] != ''){
      if($menufooterlist['id'] = '14'){
        $menufooteroverzicht .= '<li class="menu-item"><a href="projects/'.$menufooterlist['alias'].'.html">'.$menufooterlist['title'].'</a></li>';
      }else if($menufooterlist['id'] = '16'){
        $menufooteroverzicht .= '<li class="menu-item"><a href="actueel/'.$menufooterlist['alias'].'.html">'.$menufooterlist['title'].'</a></li>';
      }else{
      $menufooteroverzicht .= '<li class="menu-item"><a href="info/'.$menufooterlist['alias'].'.html">'.$menufooterlist['title'].'</a></li>';
    }
  }
}
echo $menufooteroverzicht;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if($menufooterlist['id'] = '14'){
```

to

```
if($menufooterlist['id'] == '14'){
```

Do the same for 16. == is used for comparison not =

Comment: Thanks! Should've known that.